# How do I write a batch script that iterates through all png files in all subfolders and does an action?

Tags: windows-7, script, batch, batch-file

I'm looking to build a small batch script that executes the command line of pngout.exe

So far I've got only this down

```
for %i in (*.png) do "g:\myfiles\_pngout.exe" "%i" /s0 /c6
```

However, for that to work I have to manually go to each folder where the pngs are and open up a cmd window from Win7 then copy and paste that line.

What I want is for that line to work say in C:\MyPNGs and it's sub-folders, like C:\MyPNGs\Avatars etc., it should iterate through all pngs and every time execute that `"g:\myfiles\_pngout.exe" "%i" /s0 /c6`

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you be opposed to using VBScript?  I'm not that experienced with batch scripts, but I could write you something that does this in VBScript in 10 minutes.

Comment: Nah, VBScript is fine too. I would just need to read up how to run it. Should be easy doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following command from a dosprompt:

```
for /r %f in (*.png) do _pngout.exe "%f"
```

or the following inside a batch file:

```
for /r %%f in (*.png) do _pngout.exe "%%f"
```

For /r also has support to give a start directory. Otherwise it'll use the current directory and get every file in all subdirectories that match your filemask.

Comment: Cheers! That did it!